# Editing attribute cell data/text in "edit" mode using QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, attribute-table, editing

I am using QGIS3.4.

I turn my layer on "edit" mode.  I want to type text into a blank cell or paste text.  I don't know why it will not allow me to enter anything while the layer is in "edit" mode.  I have been able to do this in the past.

I am fairly new to QGIS so some of the following answers might not make sense due to my lack of knowledge but here we go. I think I may already know what is wrong but I am answering the questions fully to assist other users like me in the future and also I do not fully understand GIS as a whole at this point.

My layers are from multiple origins.  Some layers are shapefiles (via zip files downloads) from my local government agency website.  The layers that I am trying to edit are shapefiles created internally from a previous a software called UDIG.

I am not sure I understand the difference between a file or a database.  I imported shapefiles into a new QGIS project.  Then I saved the QGIS project to my local drive.  From there, I downloaded the QGIS Cloud plugin to create some online maps.

At first, the file was saved locally on my drive.  After using the QGIS Cloud plugin, I believe the file/database is stored basically on QGIS Cloud.  I have lost some data and had problems not knowing how QGIS cloud is handling my data.

I think the file type is all Shapefiles.  I really couldn't explain the differences in each of a Shapefile, a Geopackage, a PostGIS database, a WMS connection etc.  I need to read more on this.  I assume Shapefiles and Geopackage files are basically the same but store my vector data a little different.  I don't know really anything about a WMS connection yet but I assume it is a way to connect remotely to a database of information without storing the information on my computer.  Basically, I open the QGIS file and it opens the WMS connection.

I have included a screenshot of what I am trying to do.

[image: Main Screen]

I have included a screenshot of my layer properties / Information tab to show the source of the layer.

[image: Layer Properties Information]

[image: What I am trying to do]

Comment: Please provide more information. What kind of data source does the layer has? Not all data types can be edited in QGIS.

Comment: In the source field under the layer properties is "QString varchar -1 -1".  Also in the Attributes Form tab under the layer properties the field box is "checked" editable. I actually cannot edit any field and I have all different types

Comment: Where is you layer from? A file or a database? From a local drive or remote? What filetype has your data: is it a Shapefile, a Geopackage, a PostGIS database, a WMS connection etc.? Please include a screenshot of your `layer properties / Information tab` if you're not sure and add it to the original question: we need to know the source of the layer. Add as well a screenshot of what you're trying to do. In "blind mode" it's almost impossible to say where the problem is.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

You try to edit the `fid`, that looks like the [unique identifyer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_identifier) (primary key) in your database. This number works for the internal administration of the database and has to be a unique number. Thus you can't (and shouldn't) change it: once set, it will remain the same. If another table is refering to this one (e.g. using a table join), after changing the `fid` the appropriate data record can't be assigned properly anymore.

Instead, create a new field called `id`, `new_id` or whatever you want and copy the values from the `fid` field there (using field calculator).

By the way: the source of your layer is a PostGIS database (at least that is what your screenshot shows), a remote one as you use QGIScloud.